# Excel Data to be updated using python in a loop

Tags: python, excel

I have below table to update in excel using python. I tried groupby and also loop or iterrow method but failed to populate values.

| AGE | INCOME | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 50,000 |  |
| 34 | 55,000 |  |
| 32 | 43,000 |  |
| 32 | 48,000 |  |
| 34 | 38,000 |  |

The aim here is to calculate and update Total column in excel. So Age=32 will have 141,000 which is the total of all entries for "32" and similarly 93,000 for "34".

Comment: Could you add more details, update in excel using python is not cleared enough, are you using pandas read excel in, or pandas then write to excel, or other library that read excel etc...

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong I am reading this table from excel in python later computation needs to be done and write to excel Total column with respective values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas. Once you've read the file, you just need to group the DataFrame by 'AGE' and calculates the sum of 'INCOME' within each age group:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('AGE')['INCOME'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it doesn't populate values against respective Age

Comment: Apologies but there was a typo in my formula and it worked well. Thanks for your help.